# Unknown error when using readtext with PDFs

Tags: r, pdf, tm, corpus, quanteda

I am a complete novice working on some textual analysis in R.

I have a folder of ~12000 PDF documents I am trying to convert into a corpus for analysis.

I have attempted to do so several different ways:

```
###Directory

directory <- "C:/Users/lewis/Desktop/Bank__Speeches/Bank__Speeches/All_Speech_Pdf/2007-2020"

##First attempt

text <- readtext(directory)

##Second attempt
text <- readtext::readtext("C:/Users/lewis/Desktop/Bank__Speeches/Bank__Speeches/All_Speech_Pdf/2007-2020")

##Third attempt

text <- readtext("C:/Users/lewis/Desktop/Bank__Speeches/Bank__Speeches/All_Speech_Pdf/2007-2020")

##Fourth attempt

corpus <- VCorpus(DirSource(directory, pattern = ".pdf"),
                  readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```

In all cases I receive the following error, which despite much googling I have not been able to find elsewhere...

**"PDF error: Expected the default config, but wasn't able to find it, or it isn't a Dictionary"**

I downloaded a separate set of PDFs as a test file and ran the same code, and it worked.

```
directory_test <- ("C:/Users/lewis/Desktop/Practice_R_data/")

text <- readtext(directory_test)
```

I have tried adding encoding=unicode-8 but that has not done anything.

I assume the problem is something to do with the PDFs, but I am not sure what? Any help would be much appreciated.

***LINK to folder with a sample of the PDFs in question*** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RFyrytj7MkzIhrf-jwttQ_LnWSn95gJk?usp=sharing

Comment: What happens when you use `pdftools::pdf_text(xxxx)` where xxxx is one of the pdfs you are trying to read? Try a test with a few pdfs in a different folder, like d:/test/pdfs/...to see if your folder structure is not impeding the process. If that doesn't help, then provide one of the pdfs that result in the error.

Comment: @phiver

That code works both with individual pdfs in the original folder and after moving them to a different folder. However when i move all 12,000 pdfs to a new folder, I get the same error messages.

Strangely, when I move a handful of the PDFs to a different folder and use the original code, I get the error messages but readtext reads the data. However for all 12,000 i only get error message and no data.

I downloaded another academic's dataset of speeches from the same site and all the code works fine for those speeches.... I have added a google drive link to some of my PDFs

Comment: Testing the 8 documents I get your error 2 times with the first 2 pdfs. But looking at the resulting data.frame all the text has been processed. The error is a notification from pdftools that there is an issue with the pdf somehow. I would say you can safely ignore it. If you really want to be sure, you should file an issue on the [github page of pdftools](https://github.com/ropensci/pdftools)

Comment: cheers mate! I ended up dividing them into groups and the upload went ahead. Thanks for all your help